# What are the allowed values for the SameSite cookie attribute in Chrome 51+

Tags: cookies, csrf-protection

Chrome 51, released May 25, 2016, adds support for the SameSite cookie attribute, which can be used to mitigate CSRF exposure.

An example Set-Cookie Response Header string for example:

I have read V7 of the [IETF spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-west-first-party-cookies-07) for this cookie enhancement and I found it ambiguous in terms of the allowable SameStrict values, and could not find any definitive guide on the entire Internets on what exact String values are supported.

Here are the three options I think/thought are valid:

1. SameSite
2. SameSite=Strict
3. SameSite=Lax

The grammar in section 3.1 suggests all are valid, but the rules in Section 4.1 (rule 1) suggest that only option 2 and 3 are valid.

So the question(s) is specifically:

- What is supported by Chrome versions 51 and newer ? (Answer: option 2 and 3 ONLY)
- What is supported by other browsers ?

Answer (score 2):

I found that Chrome will honour SameSite=Strict and SameSite=Lax, but if you just add SameSite to your cookie string then the cookie will not be used at all !

This is the expected behaviour of chromium, there is some discussion in [this chromium issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=600983#c2).

Best unofficial non-spec writeup I can find is [here](https://chloe.re/2016/04/13/goodbye-csrf-samesite-to-the-rescue/)